# Using SQLite in Windows Phone 8 - relations and queries

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 App (C#) that will use SQLite with the Native wrapper.  I have it set up and working, but I haven't found much documentation except how to download it and add basic tables.  Therefore, I have a few questions:

1. Is there any way to specify relations between objects?
2. Is it possible to do Complex SQL queries using the QueryAsync() method?  I would like to do a query that joins multiple tables and does a LIKE operator to search for matching entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) along with [SQLite-net-wp8](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8) for native SQLite access in wp8.

> Is there any way to specify relations between objects?

Unfortunately no. However, you can specify `[Indexed]` attribute on your foreign keys for performance. Of course, you can always pre-build your tables using SQL scripts in which case you can specify relations.

> Is it possible to do Complex SQL queries using the QueryAsync()
>   method? I would like to do a query that joins multiple tables and does
>   a LIKE operator to search for matching entries.

You can build complex queries but you have to execute SQL scripts for joins as the library doesn't support that yet.

```cs
string myQuery = "....";
var result = await db.QueryAsync<MyTableType>(myQuery, myParams);
```